# Hide inherited property in page properties dialog (Touch UI)

Tags: aem, aem-6, aem-touch-ui

I'd like to hide a property within a certain tab that is inherited from /libs/wcm/foundation/components/basicpage/v1/basicpage (e.g. hideInNav property in basic tab).

This change should only affect one page-rendering component, so I **don't** want to do an overlay of  the Foundation page dialog in /apps/foundation/components/basicpage/v1/basicpage/tabs/basic. Therefore I tried using sling:hideChildren, but I did not manage to accomplish to make it work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
    <content jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
            <tabs jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                    <basic jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">

                        <!-- that does not work either -->
                        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" sling:hideChildren="*">
                            <column jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                    <title jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">

                                            <!-- that does not work -->
                                            <title jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" sling:hideProperties="*"/>
                                        </items>
                                    </title>

                                    <!-- that does not work -->
                                    <moretitles
                                        cq:showOnCreate="{Boolean}false"
                                        cq:hideOnEdit="{Boolean}true"
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                    </moretitles>
                                </items>
                            </column>
                        </items>
                    </basic>

                    <!-- that works -->
                    <advanced jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" sling:hideResource="{Boolean}true"/>
                </items>
            </tabs>
        </items>
    </content>
</jcr:root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, figured out a solution (for AEM 6.4). You have to use the Resource Merger with an override:

**The override is absolutely necessary to merge the properties from the inherited page with the properties of the super/parent page! And it requires an absolute path.**

`<basic jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" path="/mnt/override/apps/[...]/components/basepage/tabs/basic"/>`

The XML file of the tabs works as you would expect it to work and you can use sling:hideChildren and all the other properties:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:granite="http://www.adobe.com/jcr/granite/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
    <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
        <column jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
            <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                <title jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                    <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" sling:hideChildren="[hideinnav]" />
                </title>
                <moretitles jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                    <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" sling:hideChildren="[pagetitle,navigationtitle,subtitle]"/>
                </moretitles>
            </items>
        </column>
    </items>
</jcr:root>
```

Example from Adobe. This commit helped me understand the differences between 6.1 and 6.4:
https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-authoring-extension-page-dialog/commit/aaa6035c8cdfcfaeb5e2157be436e1fccfbe22db

Comment: Nice find. This is how to use sling resource merger with basicpage dialog tabs.